# Unusal Error during Java EE SDK Install

Tags: java

I have installed jdk 7, installed netbeans which supports the new version. After that, i tried to installed java ee 6, with jdk 7 and it says, `Could not find required version of Java(TM) 2 Runtime`. Despite with the availability of jre 7.
why does java ee 6 with jdk 7, needs jre6  to install simply beats me.

How to overcome this? 
Will I get a problem, if i install two versions of jdk, jdk6 and jdk7?

Comment: Have you resolved the problem? Has it anything to do with the JAVA_HOME variable?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov, No, It was a version problem. I downloaded the the next JDK version and it worked.